# Identifying collection of (related) sci-fi short stories with general theme(s) of prejudice/freedom

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recall reading a short-story collection in early '70s; the collection could have been much older, since it was most likely a library book. I think it was from one author, but am not positive.

What I recall is that each story had some kind of tie-in to an earlier story. One of the stories involved animals genetically modified to be servants rebelling against humans for their freedom. A later story involved robots (or something similar) rebelling against the genetically modified animals for *their* freedom.

I seem to recall themes of prejudice and freedom running through at least some of the stories.

Comment: Definitely some more details required, are you able to expand on any of the plot points at all? Any character(s) you remember?

Comment: Cordwainer Smith's Instrumentality stories? "The Ballad of Lost C'Mell" is about animal-derived "underpeople" gaining their rights.

Comment: Any story you might remember might be recognized by someone else even if they haven't read that book, if that single story was reprinted elsewhere.  And if one or two stories are recognized, it's usually relatively easy to find which book the others would be from.  So even the smallest details about the other stories might help.

Comment: @Organic, the reference to "under people" is very familiar. Will see where that clue takes me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reference to *underpeople* by **Cordwainer Smith** was correct. Just finished a related anthology of Cordwainer Smith stories called *We the Underpeople*. The data of publication of this anthology (2008) and the Introduction (2002) were too new to have been the collection I originally read.  Unfortunately, I could not get my hands on one of the original collections.  However, there were several stories I did recognize including "Under Old Earth", "The Ballad of Lost C'Mell" and "Mother Hitton's Littul Kittens".

Comment: [This collection](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35767) from 1975 contains the three stories you mention, is that early enough?